# Start menu icons move - Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, icons, start-menu

I have the icons on my start menu set to the smallest size, and in a particular order. When I start my machine and login, the order has changed. I have been unable to recreate this issue when shutting the machine down and starting up again, or from logging out and back in again, so I'm not sure on the circumstances that cause this to occur.

Any there any cases where tiles may be re-ordered?

**How the icons should be:** [image]

**What they are like after they've moved:**[image]

Comment: Is this a work machine or personal computer? If it is a work machine it could be Group Policy that changes the order of the icons.

Comment: It's my personal machine, funnily enough, my work machine is the same OS, and part of a domain with group policies, but it never happens on there.